# How to restart a seed node after its process crashes?

Tags: cassandra

Is there any differences between replacing a dead node and restarting a dead node, specially for seed nodes ? Actually, I'm a little bit confused about how to restart a dead seed node.

When the process of a seed node crashes, should I restart it without doing any changes to cassandra.yaml ? Or, like replacing a seed node, should I remove its IP address from the seeds list (cassandra.yml) on each node ?

The [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_replace_seed_node.html) is not clear about that. It only deals about how to replace a dead node by another machine.

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply restarting a dead seed node, then you shouldn't need to alter your `cassandra.yaml` file before the restart.  As long as you have addressed whatever caused the node to die, and your node has not been down longer than `gc_grace_seconds` (see note below), then restarting shouldn't be an issue.

The concerns noted in the documentation you have linked center around *replacing* dead seed nodes.  The problem with replacing seed nodes, is that the new node will not bootstrap into the cluster if it is configured as a seed.  In that case, a different node in the cluster should be promoted to be a seed node.

**Note:** the [About Deletes](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_about_deletes_c.html) section of the documentation warns about bringing a node back that has been down a long time.  Specifically, longer than the value set for `gc_grace_seconds` (or the shortest value set, if you have changed it on any individual tables).

> ...if a node is down
>   longer than the grace period, the node can miss the delete because the
>   tombstone disappears after gc_grace_seconds. Cassandra always attempts
>   to replay missed updates when the node comes back up again. After a
>   failure, it is a best practice to run node repair to repair
>   inconsistencies across all of the replicas when bringing a node back
>   into the cluster. If the node doesn't come back within
>   gc_grace,_seconds, remove the node, wipe it, and bootstrap it again.